# Is it possible to add notes to My Profiles with a multi-farm deployment?

Tags: my-site, my-profile, multiple-farms

I'm accessing a SharePoint 2010 implementation that has been setup by someone else and I don't have admin access to explore further. I also don't have a multi-farm VM setup available to test on at the moment.

There are 3 farms: ASIAPC, EMEA, and AMERICAS. Users can create a My Profile only. This will be be located on the farm that is closest to them. If they are on the ASIAPAC farm and they try to tag something on the EMEA farm it doesn't appear on their profile. If they tag something on the ASIAPAC farm it appears on their profile page.

Is this the expected behavior? When you tag something and return to add more tags the existing ones are listed, but the links below "Recent Activities" on the team site add tags popup point back to the My Site URL on the EMEA farm. Following these takes you back to your canonical My Site URL on ASIAPAC. I assume the redirection is caused by the [Trusted My Site Host Locations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx#section2) setting.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that there are multiple components involved.

You have the base user profiles which includes the attributes about    the people. You have the Social Data which has the extended info like    tags and notes. You have the Personal or My Content sites which is    the site collection they would own.

As stefan mentioned, you can share the user profiles, so that they set up in one farm centrally, and then all three farms would be able to interact with the one service app.  This means that you only have to maintain the user profile sync centrally. The personal sites can be houses in different locations.  The challenge here is that it may be slow for users in the other two geos.

You also have the option of maintaining the three user profile services, but can offer profile synchronization between services which can propagate the profile info AND social data to the other farms.  This should offer better performance for users working with sites from any of the geos.

Comment: Just to add more to what Mike has said here, you can User Profiles Replication Engine to replicate profiles between three instances of the User Profile Service Application that run between different farms. I’ve used User Profiles Replication Engine tool a number of times with customers to replicate user profile data between farms. I would rather be fancy keeping User Profiles and social data in their respective farms and let User Profiles Replication Engine to perform sync.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can share some service applications among multiple farms. One of those Service applications is the User Profile Service Application.
You will find more information on this Sharing of Service Application in the TechNet:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100.aspx